# Android Display Toast When Alarm Timer Is Triggered

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how alarm timers work so I can trigger an event when a user selects the predefined times in the app. To start off I just want to show a toast so I can clearly see the app is working. But when I run the app and set the time for 10 seconds the class handling my Intent never seems to get called.

I am using `Log.d` in the Main and I can see it being logged correctly when the button is clicked. But the event does not fire off at the selected time.

This is the function that fires off when the button is clicked and the Log.d is displayed in the console.

```
  public void scheduleAlarm()
    {
        Long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
        Log.d("logs", "This is running in the main act");
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, affirmationSchedule.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Has Been Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And this is the class which handles the code to run when the alarm time comes

```
public class affirmationSchedule extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("logs", "This function is running");
        Toast.makeText(context, "this is a toast working.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

Log.d never displays. the toast in this class never displays.
```

This leads me to believe I am not creating my object correctly.

This is how I am registering receiver in the manifest.

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.wuno.wunoaffirmations"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.wuno.BroadcastReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Any ideas?

This might be relevant,

After I click the button and the original toast goes away. This pops up in console.

```
05-16 23:10:11.989 14242-14268/com.wuno.wunoaffirmations E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4015c60
```

But not in ten seconds. More like 5.The alarmManager is set for 10 seconds.

Comment: You could've just edited your original question. Anyway, the `name` attribute on the `<receiver>` element needs to be your `BroadcastReceiver`'s class name. Everything else looks OK, but you don't really need the `<intent-filter>`, or the `enabled` or `exported` attributes.

Comment: If your Receiver class is in the main source folder - i.e., where your main `Activity` is usually located - it would just be `<receiver android:name=".affirmationSchedule" />`. You might also want to use the `setExact()` method, at least while testing. The `set()` method is inexact since KitKat, and can vary quite a bit.

Comment: Well, there's a way to check your app's alarms with adb, but if you're that your `scheduleAlarm()` method is running, then your alarm should be getting set just fine. Dunno. Everything seems good. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project, and rebooting the device or emulator you're testing on. Oh, and make sure your `<receiver>` is inside the `<application>` tags in the manifest.

Comment: @MikeM. is inside the <application> tags in the manifest. Yep that was it.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Is it working?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I did not have it inside <application. thanks for sticking with me man.

Comment: @MikeM. Do you think the way I am going about this is reasonable? Or the example below from Zeeshan Shabbir makes more sense and I should redo things to that standard?

Comment: It depends on what the intended use is. Just showing a `Toast` in the Receiver - or any other simple, quick operation - is fine. If you plan on doing anything heavy - e.g., database stuff, network transactions, etc. - then starting a `Service` from the Receiver is the way to go. The `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` will allow anything you need to do to happen when the device is asleep, but if that's not a concern, then you can stick with the regular class. The boot Receiver is useful if you need to reschedule your alarms after boot, 'cause alarms don't survive rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how i used alarm manager within a project of mine. Basically i followed some code from a google's app code. so here it is. I hope this will help you.

How to use it? Well just Create instance of AlramReciver and then set it.

```
private AlarmReceiver alarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
alramReceiver.setAlram();
```

This is helper class which set the alram receiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private static PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*
         * If your receiver intent includes extras that need to be passed along to the
         * service, use setComponent() to indicate that the service should handle the
         * receiver's intent. For example:
         *
         * ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
         *      MyService.class.getName());
         *
         * // This intent passed in this call will include the wake lock extra as well as
         * // the receiver intent contents.
         * startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
         *
         * In this example, we simply create a new intent to deliver to the service.
         * This intent holds an extra identifying the wake lock.
         */
        Intent service= new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        startWakefulService(context,service);
    }

    /**
     *set the alram
     * @param context
     */
    public void setAlarm(Context context){
        alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60, alarmIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    /**
     * cancels the alram
     * @param context
     */
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context){
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmManager!= null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
        // Disable {@code SampleBootReceiver} so that it doesn't automatically restart the
        // alarm when the device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

This is bootReceiver class used when your device goes off and switch on again

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    AlarmReceiver alarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarmReceiver.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

This is intent service class here you have to write your logic for your app.

public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

```
public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //Write the logice here
    AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent); // this tell if the related work is complete then system tracks for another alram.
}
```

Last you have to make changes in your manifest.

```
    <service android:name="AlarmService" />
    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="BootReceiver" />
```

I hope this will help you atleast. P.s you don't have to post same question twice.

Comment: Hey man everything makes sense to me accept this part. private AlarmReceiver alarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
alarmReceiver.setAlarm(); Would you mind adding some details about this?

Comment: You will have to use this snippet of code where or in any activity from where you want to fire alram and set it. Then you can cancel same alram in any class or activiy by creating instance of same class and calling cancelalram()

Comment: Yes I get that. But I am not understand what parameters it takes.  When I add this in the MainActivity    private AlarmReceiver alarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
    alarmReceiver.setAlarm(); the setAlarm cannot be resolved

Comment: setAlram() should be declared public

Comment: Ya that does not work either. I am trying to figure out how to use your example to setAlarm. So If I want to pass a time to set alarm to the setAlarm function. But I cannot get setAlarm to resolve in MainActivity

Comment: Its strange. it should be working. Did you copy and pasted exact same code to your project>?

Comment: ``` https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html  ``` copy this link and download the sample app. Inspect their code. It is exact same as mine with more details it would help you understand more

Comment: Yes I did. minus the typos on setAlarm of course. That is all I have changed. No matter what I do I cannot get setAlarm to resolve. So for example right now I am trying to get it to work by creating an object in the MainActivity and then adding an alarm when a button is clicked. Also just adding the new object like you display in MainActivity anywhere setAlarm() will not resolve.

Comment: Oh sorry. setAlram requires context. You would have to do it ```setAlarm(this);```

Comment: Yes I got that haha. thanks though. The last problem I was facing is an exception on AlarmReceiver  startWakefulService(context,service); I needed a permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> it fix the problem

Comment: Oh yeah sorry i forgot to add that in answer. Sometimes lots of programming makes you dumb. Right now i am being one. Cuz doing it from previous 48 hours without break. You can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void scheduleAlarm()
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("logs", "This is running in the main act");
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, affirmationSchedule.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal + 10000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Has Been Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class affirmationSchedule extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("logs", "This function is running");
        Toast.makeText(context, "this is a toast so this is working.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

In manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.wuno.affirmationSchedule"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.wuno.BroadcastReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```